# Есть ли в предложении сравнительный оборот?

Tags: пунктуация, как, сравнительный-оборот

В предложении ***Любить детей как мама*** нужна запятая перед ***как***?

Answer (score 1):

Конечно, перед нами сравнительный оборот и запятая нужна: любить так, как любит мама,

но не в качестве её и не "мамообразно". )))

Answer (score 0):

Можно предположить, что предложение стилистически не очень корректно (хотя для окончательного суждения требуется контекст).

Смысл такой: **Любить детей материнской любовью**. В этом предложении  обстоятельство входит в основное сообщение, нет паузы и обособления.

А вот в заданном предложении паузы тоже не должно быть, сравнительный оборот  занимает место основного обстоятельства, но при такой структуре **он должен обособляться.**

**И вывод:** надо взять полный текст и выразить ту же мысль в более корректной форме.

Comment: Полного текста нет, это заголовок статьи.

Comment: Ну тогда это неудачный заголовок (некорректная структура, неясная семантика, проблемная пунктуация).

Comment: Это уже не от меня зависит. Спасибо за советы!

Comment: Но Вы же проверяете постановку знаков препинания. А если предложение имеет грамматические или стилистические погрешности, то говорить о правильных запятых не имеет смысла.

Comment: Это заказная статья, за нее платят клиенты, поэтому заголовки менять не можем. У нас не все так просто. Еще раз спасибо за ваше мнение!